# Does Core Data get loaded to the app store automatically

Tags: core-data

I have built an app that uses Core Data extensively.  I am about to submit the app to Apple for approval.  Will the core data get loaded to the app store automatically?  And when users buy the app will the core data go to their phones automatically?  Or do I need to set up a routine to generate the Core Data when the app is first started?

Comment: "Core Data" is a framework for creating data models with a backing store such as sqlite. You then create, retrieve, update, and delete that data using the Core Data framework APIs. Saying "Core Data get loaded to the app store" does not make sense. Do you mean that your app when published to the app store will be repopulated with data?

Comment: Obviously I haven't expressed my question very well.  In creating the app I have built methods to create information, stored in core data.  This all works fine.  When I load the app into the store will this information go with it - is the information already in core data part of the app?

Comment: ok I understand. See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include a repopulated sqlite database file in your app's bundle. See my answer about how to do this:

[Core Data information in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615078/core-data-information-in-application/7632691#7632691)